# how to get file lastmodified us United States Locale Settings

Tags: android, date, locale

here is my code.

My problem is lastmodified time come to me as Turkish but i want to handle it as US.

how i do it??

```
File f = new File(GlobalVariables.jsonDir + categoryCode);
            if(f.exists())
                fd = f.lastModified();
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you looking for a specific format, e.g. 'July 8, 2011'?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, just looked at the API but something like:

```
long dateInMilliseconds = file.lastModified();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateInMilliseconds);
Date usDate = calendar.getTime()
```

Comment: actually i try it but already, i run this code     String fileDate = (String) DateFormat.format("E, dd MMM yyyy h:mm:ssaa", fd) + " GMT";  String filedate is come to me as "Per,08 Oca..." this is turkish..  when i changed my device language this code return to me as "Fri, 08 Jun.." .. Now, i am saving date-modified header my http post and i send back to it.  İ dont know maybe this is not actually right way but it is working..

Comment: It's hard to say what's right or wrong without really understanding what you're trying to do. Are you trying to handle date formats? Or language?

Comment: i am trying to handle date formats, but date format come to me as device language but i want to handle date format as US..